# Return every row from has_many association after filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Having models Author and Book where Author has_many books, and a scope on the Author like:

```
scope :by_books,->(book_ids) { joins(:books).where(books: { id: book_ids }) }
```

with the intent of filtering Authors if they are authors of a given book, results only the author and the specified books only in the result of:

```
Author.by_books(1).includes(:books).as_json(include: :books)
```

Whereas I would expect to have all the books of the author in the resulting json. I can do that by using `.joins(:books)` instead of `.includes(:books)` but now I am completely confused about what joins and includes do. I wonder if somebody could give me an explanation where my expectation goes wrong.

(The code given is an analog of my actual, it might be flawed in terms of syntax but I believe the behavior is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

```
Author.create!([
  { name: 'Author 1',
    books: [ Book.new(name: 'Book 1 of A1'), Book.new(name: 'Book 2 of A1') ] },
  { name: 'Author 2',
    books: [ Book.new(name: 'Book 1 of A2') ] },
  { name: 'Author 3' } 
])
```

You have to be careful with `joins` and `includes`, they return different results depending on associations.

We have 'Author 1' who has two books, 'Author 2' who has one book, and 'Author 3' without books.

`joins` does an INNER JOIN and instantiates new objects based on database result, this could return duplicate records and not return records that have no association

```
>> Author.joins(:books)
  Author Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" INNER JOIN "books" ON "books"."author_id" = "authors"."id"
=> [ #<Author:0x00007f0dd278d818 id: 1, name: "Author 1">,
     #<Author:0x00007f0dd278d688 id: 1, name: "Author 1">, # duplicate
     #<Author:0x00007f0dd278d598 id: 2, name: "Author 2">] 
   # 'Author 3' is not in the result
```

`includes` is a rails solution to `N+1`. It runs two queries aka `preload` or a single query aka `eager_load`

```
>> Author.includes(:books)
  Author Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors"
  Book Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."author_id" IN ($1, $2, $3)  [["author_id", 1], ["author_id", 2], ["author_id", 3]]
=> [ #<Author:0x00007f0dd27e59c8 id: 1, name: "Author 1">, 
     #<Author:0x00007f0dd27e5900 id: 2, name: "Author 2">, 
     #<Author:0x00007f0dd27e5838 id: 3, name: "Author 3">]
```

When you have conditions it does an `eager_load` in a single query

```
# same as  Author.eager_load(:books)
>> Author.includes(:books).references(:books)
  SQL (1.0ms)  SELECT "authors"."id" AS t0_r0, "authors"."name" AS t0_r1, "books"."id" AS t1_r0, "books"."name" AS t1_r1, "books"."author_id" AS t1_r2 FROM "authors" LEFT OUTER JOIN "books" ON "books"."author_id" = "authors"."id"                                                          
=> [ #<Author:0x00007f0dd283a1f8 id: 1, name: "Author 1">, 
     #<Author:0x00007f0dd2839bb8 id: 2, name: "Author 2">, 
     #<Author:0x00007f0dd2839780 id: 3, name: "Author 3">]
```

With this you get all the authors with or without books, books objects are preloaded into author object.

```
>> Author.includes(:books).to_a.first.instance_variable_get('@association_cache')
  Author Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors"
  Book Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."author_id" IN ($1, $2, $3)  [["author_id", 1], ["author_id", 2], ["author_id", 3]]
=> {:books=>
  #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation:0x00007f0dd28ff9d0
   @association_ids=nil,
   @association_scope=nil,
   @disable_joins=false,
   @loaded=true,
   @owner=#<Author:0x00007f0dd28f83b0 id: 1, name: "Author 1">,
   @reflection=#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection:0x00007f0dd58a3f38 ... >,
   @replaced_or_added_targets=#<Set: {}>,
   @stale_state=nil,
   @target=[ #<Book:0x00007f0dd28fc230 id: 1, name: "Book 1 of A1", author_id: 1>, 
             #<Book:0x00007f0dd28fc078 id: 2, name: "Book 2 of A1", author_id: 1>]>}
  #          ^
  # books are preloaded

>> Author.includes(:books).to_a.last.instance_variable_get('@association_cache')
  Author Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors"
  Book Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."author_id" IN ($1, $2, $3)  [["author_id", 1], ["author_id", 2], ["author_id", 3]]
=> {:books=>
  #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation:0x00007f0dd2a017c0
   ...,
   @target=[]>}
  #        ^
  # doesn't have any books
```

When includes does an `eager_load` it runs LEFT OUTER JOIN so you get all the authors and rails combines duplicated results, unlike the `joins` method.

```
>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(Author.eager_load(:books).to_sql).to_a
   (0.8ms)  SELECT "authors"."id" AS t0_r0, "authors"."name" AS t0_r1, "books"."id" AS t1_r0, "books"."name" AS t1_r1, "books"."author_id" AS t1_r2 FROM "authors" LEFT OUTER JOIN "books" ON "books"."author_id" = "authors"."id"                                                                                                                                                          
=>
[{"t0_r0"=>1, "t0_r1"=>"Author 1", "t1_r0"=>1, "t1_r1"=>"Book 1 of A1", "t1_r2"=>1},
 {"t0_r0"=>1, "t0_r1"=>"Author 1", "t1_r0"=>2, "t1_r1"=>"Book 2 of A1", "t1_r2"=>1}, 
# ^ duplicate `Author 1` like the `joins` method
 {"t0_r0"=>2, "t0_r1"=>"Author 2", "t1_r0"=>3, "t1_r1"=>"Book 1 of A2", "t1_r2"=>2},
 {"t0_r0"=>3, "t0_r1"=>"Author 3", "t1_r0"=>nil, "t1_r1"=>nil, "t1_r2"=>nil}]
```

'Author 1' results get merged into one `Author` object.

You're running `joins` and `includes` at the same time which combined does an `eager_load` style query.

```
Author.joins(:books).includes(:books).where(books: {id: [1,2]})
 # INNER JOIN 
 # 2 database results
 # 1 Author object 
 # Books are preloaded
```

```
Author.joins(:books).where(books: {id: [1,2]})
 # INNER JOIN
 # 2 database results
 # 2 Author objects
 # No books are loaded
```

```
Author.includes(:books).where(books: {id: [1,2]})
 # LEFT OUTER JOIN
 # 2 database results
 # 1 Author object 
 # Books are preloaded
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you for taking the time! 
Considering all of these, do you agree that in order to be able to apply these scope style conditions(with joins in them) while loading all records from associations **and** avoid n+1 at the same time when applying `.as_json` a solution then can be to do something like `list = Authors.from("(#{list.to_sql}) as authors")` before applying the `.includes(:books).as_json(include: :books)`. It works in my testing but I wonder...

Comment: I'd avoid over-optimizing. Using nested select works, but building  a single big query is not alway faster. Unless you have actual big slow queries. In which case using cache would be faster.

Comment: I see, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 2):

- `joins` is a pure SQL word query to join 2 tables.
- `includes` is for eager loading (avoid `n+1` query issue)